# Entangled photons production and interference

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, quantum-spin

Can entangled photons be produced simultaneously and have the same **frequency** and **opposite polarization spins**? What can happen if this pair is led to **interfere** with each other? If they are cancelling out what is going on about the **energy** conservation law?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, one can produce such an entangled pair of photons. It is done with degenerate type II [spontaneous parametric down-conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_parametric_down-conversion). Here, "degenerate" means that the wavelength (frequency) of the two photons are the same. The "type II" is a phase matching condition that is used to get entanglement in polarization. Hence, the two photons would have orthogonal polarizations.

Unfortunately one cannot interfere two different photons. Usual first order interference (i.e., the normal optical interference one gets with optical interferometers) implies that every photons interferes with itself. However, there are higher order quantum interference effects such as the [Hong-Ou-Mandel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong%E2%80%93Ou%E2%80%93Mandel_effect) effect. In such a case it is the whole state (pair of photons) that interfers with itself. One finds that whenever there is destructive interference at one point, there is constructive interference at another point. So energy is always conserved.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to understand this better if you draw out a diagram of an apparatus to bring the two photons together -- like a Michaelson interferometer.  Keep in mind that a photon does not follow just one path; it is a probability distribution that follows *all possible paths*.  So if it cannot be detected at one output face of the interferometer, it *can* be detected at the other output face.

In other words, destructive interference doesn't destroy photons; it just makes them undetectable at one place but detectable someplace else.  Whenever there is destructive interference in one location, there is constructive interference in another location.